# ons-dialog data binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

Using a ons-dialog to show a popup to prompt the user to sign up for a newsleter. I have it on a 3 second timeout so that they can't just imediately quit the prompt without either reading it/waiting the 3 seconds.

I want the show the dialog with the 'close' button disabled then un-disable the button programmatically.

Here is my JavaScript code :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    try {                              
        $scope.myBool = "FASLE";
        document.getElementById('cancelButton').setAttribute('disabled', '');
    } catch(e) { 
        alert(e);
    }
}, 3000);
```

This is my button code :

```
<ons-toolbar-button var="cancelButton" ng-disabled="{{myBool}}" id="cancelButton" ng-click="naviDialog.hide()">X</ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
```

I have also put {{myBool}} in a text field of a dummy button to watch if it changes.... it does not change and update the screen, I have to click the dummy button for it to change the text in that button. However, even after I can view the change in the variable, the ons-button in the toolbar in my ons-dialog does not enable..

Seems if there is an issue with the binding? Though I'm not too sure....

Anyone have this problem?

EDIT:

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <ons-navigator var="myNav">
        <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar inline>
            <div class="center">
                Join Us
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-disabled="myBool" var="cancelButton" id="cancelButton" ng-click="naviDialog.hide()">X</ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <div style="text-align: center">

            <p>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-4x"></i>
            </p>
            <p>
            Join our mailing list to receive special offers and insider information.
            </p>
            <input type="email" class="text-input text-input--underbar"
                placeholder="Email" value="" style="color:black; width:80%;">
                <p>
                <ons-button onclick="myNav.pushPage('signup.html')">Submit</ons-button>
                </p>
                </div>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-navigator>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
app.controller('welcomePopupController', function($http, $scope, $compile, $sce, $window, filterFilter){
            $scope.myBool = true;
                    setTimeout(function(){                        
                               try{
                               console.log('re-enabling button');
                               $scope.myBool = false;
                               }
                               catch(e){alert(e);}
                               }, 3000);
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use interpolation in the `ng-disabled` directive.

It should be:

```
ng-disabled="myBool"
```

**Update**

An additional problem was the use of `setTimeout`. `setTimeout` executes outside the Angular environment so it won't kick off a digest cycle and watchers won't pick up the changes in the properties.

The solution is to use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) which will invoke a new digest cycle.

As an extra, `$timeout` makes the application more testable.

[This](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/timeout-interval.html) seems like a good article about `$timeout`.

Comment: I made that change, and still not updating the view when the variable is changed.

Comment: And if you use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`? Inject it just like $window and the others, and try it with that. `$timeout(function() { try { console.log('re-enabling button'); $scope.myBool = false; } catch(e) { alert(e); } }, 3000);`

Comment: That did the trick. using $timeout. Didn't try injecting it with $window. What part of the docs would cover setTimeout doesn't work and why $timeout does?